# Using constants instead of numbers - c

Tags: c, conventions

I'm currently learning c, and our teacher told us we should never use plain numbers in code, and always use constants.

For example:

Don't do this:

```c
if (age >= 18) {...}
```

Do this:

```c
#define MIN_AGE 18
// ...
if (age >= MIN_AGE) {...}
```

They did not give us any reasoning for why to do this, and I'm left confused. Is this actually recommended? And why?

Comment: "Never" is a strong word, but otherwise yes, it's recommended. Let's say you want to change the min age. If you didn't put it into a constant, changing it would be harder, especially if the program is large and it's mentioned more than once in the code.

Comment: I would assume that "they" meant something like `if (age >= MIN_AGE)` instead.

Comment: Also please read about [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right, I had a mistake. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But what if I use 18 for this specific purpose only once? Do I still need to declare a constant?

Comment: @3174N well if your teacher says you do, then you do, otherwise they'll take away marks from your grade... but in real software, if you think you'll only use it once, then you don't need to make it a constant. I hate teachers that teach "always" like this.

Comment: Context. When seeing `MIN_AGE` in an expression you know what the number represents, *even out of usage context* : a minimum age. When seeing `18` in code you *must* decipher the context of usage, i.e. `if (age >= 18)`, and only then can you conclude (perhaps wrongly) that `18` must be some "minimum" threshold. As a bonus it also allows you to change the value in one place and have it ripple through all uses.

Comment: Assuming the program is long enough, finding even a single use of the number can take some time. And, when someone is going to change it, they won't know that it's only mentioned once.

Comment: I have seen people write `#define ONE 1`, `#define TWO 2` etc. Keeping magic numbers in constants is typically a good idea. But not all numbers are "magic". Some have more descriptive powers as is, rather than a label. Never turn good ideas into a religion. (Except for the good idea of not turning things into a religion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to use variables is that is much easier for maintenance and visualization. In the code without the variable that you showed, you would not have much of a problem changing the value directly in the `if` statement because you're using it only once.

```c
if (age >= 18) {...}
```

So if you need to change the value to 17 (as an example) you could just do this:

```c
if (age >= 17) {...}
```

But imagine if you had a lot more `if` statements in your code, like in the example below:

```c
if (age >= 18) {...}
if (age >= 18) {...}
if (age >= 18) {...}
```

You would need to change it in every statement, one by one. Using a variable would be a lot easier because you could just change the value assigned to the variable:

```c
#define MIN_AGE 17
```

And all the other `MIN_AGE` variables would be already correct:

```c
if (age >= MIN_AGE) {...}
if (age >= MIN_AGE) {...}
if (age >= MIN_AGE) {...}
```

Besides, it's a lot easier to understand the meaning of `MIN_AGE`, the code will better to read and understand.

Sorry for my bad English btw!

Comment: Using a constant is especially handy for long fancy numbers like the value of PI. Keying in M_PI is easier than typing in 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288 every time, and if you *do* mistype it, the compiler will complain for the missing #define, but not for the incorrect literal number.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this is to give names to variables. Why is 18 special? If we're talking about buying alcohol in the US we might have a macro:

```
#define MIN_AGE_TO_PURCHASE_ALCOHOL 18
```

That string is far easier for the **programmer** to understand than just 18. Especially when you continue to support this code 10 years later.

Comment: It's not "far easier to understand", because 10 years later you'll still know that you have to be 18 to buy alcohol (or that you used to be). It's better because if it *changes* you don't have to remember all the places where you wrote 18!

Comment: @user253751 Maybe in this particular case you might remember that, if the rest of the context is well established. But in general it is very easy to forget the significance of some random number in some random place.